# Horizontal justified menu in CSS with bar in space

Tags: css

I have used the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536/how-do-i-really-justify-a-horizontal-menu-in-htmlcss) question to create a horizontal menu where each item is evenly spaced.

Here is my version:

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="first">
      <a href="#" title="Home Page">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About&ensp;us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">What&ensp;we&ensp;cover</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Monitoring&ensp;agencies</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Publishers</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact&ensp;us</a>
    </li>
  <span></span>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#navigation {
    text-align: justify;
}

#navigation ul span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
}

#navigation ul {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}

#navigation ul li {
    display: inline
}

#navigation ul li a {
    display: inline;
    border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
}

#navigation ul li.last a {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Is there a way to make the vertical lines move to the right such that they are halfway between the end of the a tags and the end of the li tags?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gjFYf/) is a fiddle.

I've added an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16563720/221683).

Comment: Would you consider a solution based on `table-cell` keeping in mind that IE7 will not recognize it without a hack?

Comment: Yes, what is the hack for IE7?

Comment: Will need to look it up, I was thinking of `inline-block`, but I think the hack is similar...

Comment: This one is tricky.  I solved a similar problem a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501067/fluid-navigation-items-of-different-widths-with-equidistant-spacing/16509901#16509901 and one optioned involved using jQuery/JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

### Hack Using Extra Elements for the Spacer Motif

Fiddle reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/bF6ey/

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul class="navigation">
  <li class="first">
    <a href="#" title="Home Page">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="spacer-motif">|</li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">About&ensp;us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="spacer-motif">|</li>
  ...
  <li class="spacer-motif">|</li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Contact&ensp;us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I added an extra list item between the links: `<li class="spacer-motif">|</li>` (yes, I cringe also...).

The CSS is as follows:

```
#navigation {
    padding: 0 20px; /* add spacing at left/right edges of list */
}
#navigation ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1%; /* force cell to shrink-to-fit text */
    outline: 1px dashed blue;
}
#navigation ul li.spacer-motif {
    width: 10%; /* force spacers to take up a lot of space */
    outline: none;
}

#navigation ul li a {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

The layout is based on using table display types.

For `ul`, use `display: table` and set the width to 100%.  Remember to zero out margin and padding values.

For `li`, use `display: table-cell` and `text-align: center`.

The trick is to force the table cells to shrink-to-fit the text labels by 
setting `width: 1%`, and then, for the `li.spacer-motif`, set `width: 10%` to force
the spacers to expand (evenly) to fill up the line.

To keep the text links from wrapping into 2 or 3 lines, set `white-space: pre` in the `<a>` elements (the links).

### Cleaning Up The Semantics

The problem here is that the link texts vary in width and this makes it impossible to simply use `table-cell`'s with a right or left border and centered text.  The extra spacing will vary among the links and the left/right border will not be evenly spaced between the link texts.

The way around this is to add extra elements.  I used a pipe (|) but I suppose you could add a pseudo-element with a 1px border and center it and so on.

However, if the elements are a problem, they could be inserted using jQuery or JavaScript.

**IE 7 Support - Hack for CSS**
If you need IE7 support, you need to adjust the CSS according to the following:
[CSS: table and table-cell replacement for IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880854/css-table-and-table-cell-replacement-for-ie7)

Answer (score 1):

here take a look at this fiddle [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gjFYf/1/)

I made some small adjustments. I changed `display:inline;` to `float:left;` and centerd the text.

The space is coming from the 5px padding i gave to the

```
ul li a
```

Comment: floating stops the menu from being justified across the width of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `display: table` on `ul` and `display: table-cell` on `li` for this.
and even padding on both sides for the `a` tag

Comment: I don't think that'll work in IE 7.

Comment: yes it wont, add a width % and float for this

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the spacing your after, something like this should work:

```
#navigation ul li a {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Change the 'px' value to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#navigation ul li a {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: -14px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

But it might not be cross-browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/gjFYf/2/

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in Chrome.

Comment: @IanWarburton I tested it in Chrome, so I'm sure it works, however it might not be the result you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `padding-right: 30px;` in `#navigation ul li a` worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working by inserting extra list elements into the list and then setting the width of these elements to a single pixel. I've also set their background color and removed the border on the hyperlinks.

New styles...

```
#navigation ul li.line {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}

#navigation ul li a {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #14328C;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

New Html snippet...

```
  <li>
    <a href="default.aspx?tabid=154">Publishers</a>
    <li class="line" />
  </li>
```

It doesn't work in IE7 though. The text align seems to ignore the extra li unless it contains content.

Its also now semantically incorrect.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ueQZP/1/).

Comment: I came up with a similar approach and semantics aside, this is the way to do it.  If the links were not in an ordered list, we could use pseudo elements and clean up the semantics.

Comment: @MarcAudet Did you get it working on IE7?

Comment: I did find a CSS hack/workaround for IE7, I posted a comment in my solution.

Comment: I'm not sure those solutions will work for me. I can't float the li's because it destroys the justified text alignment and the the li's are already floated. I think that I may just turn off the vertical bars on IE7. Screw  'em.

Comment: Your site will still work without the separators... I agree, there is only so much you can do!  You could always try a jQuery assisted solution if someone really insisted.  All the best!

Comment: I just suggested jQuery and got an, 'oh nooo...'. ;)